# CMD script using "attrib -h -s -a q:\02__" goes into a loop

Tags: windows-10, command-line

Opening a command prompt (cmd) and using `attrib -h -s -a D:\001__` works fine creating a script file with just that command create a loop and the command gets executed repeatedly.

<s>Is there a way to fix this?</s> The Problem was that the script file was named `attrib.cmd`. Any insight on why this happens will be appreciated <s>as well</s>... (I assume it's s.th. along the lines that `attrib` is "first" evaluated as a command to run a script with the name 'attrib.cmd' and only if the file doesn't exist it will execute the command `attrib`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the order of extensions inside PATHEXT environment variable. Initially .Exe is before .Bat/.Cmd files, but later the extension could be changed I think. But still if there are conflicts, it's better to use `attrib.exe`, you can easily replace using the Replace dialog on any text editor.